# Random Lightning Strikes

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I have been playing FTB for a while now and for some reason I am getting random lightning strikes occurring. There is no storm and the affect does not change when I disable the weather.

I have read up on it and apparently it is due to Thaumcraft and having too much flux in one area (I haven't started on thaumcraft as of yet). I noticed that it said the flux could be reduced by planting silver wood trees. I did this (planted at least 7) and they all grew but unfortunately the lightning is still occurring.

Is this a bug because it is becoming really destructive and laggy with multiple chunks loaded at the same time in the nether and due to quarries. How can I fix this? I have turned off fire spread but I just want to know how to stop the lightning.

Also now that I have planted all these silvewood trees, creepy voices are being played (hopefully through the game). Is this normal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out and it had nothing to do with thaumcraft. I have been breeding bees and have recently stumbled upon the excited branch of bees. I remove them from the apiary and the lightning stopped instantly. Apparently it is an affect of these bees to cause lightning strikes.

Comment: you can breed that trait out of them or use the extra bees machines to remove it